# Is there a possibility to raise an exception if message broker is down?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using Masstransit with RabbitMQ, log4net for logging and everything works just fine. But when RabbitMQ server is down I noticed that log is filled with errors:

> **ERROR - RabbitMQ Connect Failed: Broker unreachable: localhost:5672/**

But it's still possible to publish messages without any limits. It looks like such messages are sent and then disappear.

Is there any possibility to raise such exceptions and handle them  manually? Or could I somehow force the `Publish` method to throw an `Exception` if the broker is down?

Below is my bus setup:

```cs
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
        { });
        cfg.UseLog4Net();
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("test-queue", ep =>
    {
        ep.StateMachineSaga(context.Resolve<ProductSaga>(),
        context.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>());
        if (ep is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator)
        {
        ((IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator)ep).PrefetchCount = 8;
        }
        ep.UseInMemoryOutbox();
    });                     
});
```

Comment: Publish will throw an exception if the broker is down.

Comment: No, it won't. That's the problem.

Comment: Did you call `.StartAsync()` on the bus, before calling publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use observers for that as described in the documentation:

- [Bus observer](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/lifecycle-observers.html)
- [Message observer](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/observers.html)

There's also the receive endpoint observer, which isn't documented but used in the health checks.

For example, in health checks, we use the bus observer like this:

```
public class ReceiveEndpointHealthCheck :
    IReceiveEndpointObserver
{
     // some more stuff

    public Task Faulted(ReceiveEndpointFaulted faulted)
    {
        var endpoint = GetEndpoint(faulted.InputAddress);

        endpoint.Ready = false;
        endpoint.LastException = faulted.Exception;

        return TaskUtil.Completed;
    }
}
```

You can instantiate such an observer and then call `bus.ConnectReceiveEndpointObserver(receiveEndpointCheck)`.

I would also suggest using [health checks](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/configuration.html#masstransit-and-aspnet-core) since it's the default way to find out if your service is healthy, not only for RMQ.